# How to avoid SML datatype repetition in structures and signatures?

Tags: module, sml, algebraic-data-types

Given a signature `A` with a datatype `t`, say

```
signature A = sig
    datatype t = T of int | S of string
end
```

Is it possible to provide an implementation (a structure) that doesn't have `t` repeated? For example, in the following signature, the definition of `t` is repeated. It's fine for small datatypes, but a little clumsy for bigger ones.

```
structure AImpl : A = struct
    datatype t = T of int | S of string
end
```

My intention is simply to give an interface, so that one can know all of the declarations. But I don't want every implementation to repeat the datatype definition.

Although it seems that a signature and a structure could both include a datatype from another structure, one would then be unable to know the datatype declaration by inspecting the signature alone. For example:

```
structure AData = struct
    datatype t = T of int | S of string
end

signature A = sig
    datatype t = datatype AData.t
end

structure a : A = struct
    open AData
end
```

Of course, this approach, though not that satisfying, is acceptable if I put both `AData` and `A` in the same `.sig` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's impossible because of how signature matching rules works in sml.

When you introduce some non-abstract type in signature every structure with
this signature must provide the same type-binding. The reason is that signatures
in sml used mainly for hiding structure details.

For example you can use abstract type to hide datatype details from structure users:

```
signature A = 
sig
  type t
end


structure AImpl :> A = 
struct
   datatype t = T of int | S of string
end
```

Or you can expose just one type constructor:

```
signature A = 
sig
  type t
  val T : int -> t
end


structure AImpl :> A = 
struct
   datatype t = T of int | S of string
end

val test = AImpl.T 12;
```

Comment: That makes sense. Signature is for hiding implementation. Just thought that I could have put auxiliary functions in another (nested) structure and open it.